# How to find the time complexity of the following code snippet

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

What is the time complexity of the following code snippet and how to calculate it.

```
 function(int n){
        for(int i = 1 ; i<=n ; i++){
            for(int j=1 ; j<=n; j+=i){
                System.out.println("*");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to show what you've done and specifically where you're stuck rather than expecting other people to do your homework for you.

Comment: Q: `How to find the time complexity of the following code snippet` A: By calculating it. (and less trolling: What do **you** think it is?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Comment: When i = 1, inner loop will iterate n times, when i = 2, inner loop will iterate n/2 times, when i=3, inner loop will iterate n/3 times...and so on. So total number of iteration in this case will be n+n/2+n/3+n/4+n/5+....upto n terms.......So what would be the final complexity according to this approach....????

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about the total work that's done. As you noted in your comment, the inner loop runs n times when i = 1, then n / 2 times when i = 2, then n / 3 times when i = 3, etc. (ignoring rounding errors). This means that the total work done is

> n + n/2 + n/3 + n/4 + ... + n/n
>
> = n(1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + ... + 1/n)

The term in parentheses is the [nth harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), denoted H<sub>n</sub>, so the work done overall is roughly nH<sub>n</sub>. It's known that H<sub>n</sub> = Θ(log n), so the total work is Θ(n log n).

Comment: Sure! Check out slides 107-115 of [these slides](http://www.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs161/cs161.1138/lectures/10/Slides10.pdf).